# renderbufferStorage fails on iPad AIR but not on iPad Retina gen 4

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I've searched for an answer to this on Google and here. I've found similar issues, but not this issue and no answer. I'm also new to xCode and Apple development and I've inherited this project after our Apple developer left.

This is using cocos2d v0.99.4-rc3, iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.3.2. Also, this worked on iOS 7.1 and before I upgraded xCode. I upgraded both xCode and the iOS on my iPad at the same time.

In the code below, the backingWidth_ and backingHeight_ are set to 1536 and 2048 on an iPad Retina, but set to 0 on the iPad AIR.

When I call glGetError() after renderbufferStorage is executed, 0x0501 (GL_INVALID_VALUE) is returned on the AIR, but 0x0000 is returned on the Retina, so I think there is an issue with renderbufferStorage when 'layer' is passed to it for the AIR. A call to glGetError() after glBindRenderbufferOES() is executed returns 0x0000 for both AIR and Retina. I have arm64, armv7, and armv7s listed for Valid Architectures in Build Settings; but only armv7 and arm64 are shown in the first line that shows Architectures, right above Base SDK.

```
- (BOOL)resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer *)layer
{   
    // Allocate color buffer backing based on the current layer size
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer_);
    [context_ renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:layer]; //This is fine on iPad Retina but causes error for AIR
    GLenum_error = glGetError(); //this returns 0x0501 (GL_INVALID_VALUE)on the iPad AIR, but 0x0000 on the Retina.

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth_); //equals 1536 on Retina, 0 on AIR
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight_); //equals 2048 on Retina, 0 on AIR

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) //this fails, so the resizeFromLayer returns NO.
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}
```

resizeFromLayer is called from layoutSubviews()

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [renderer_ resizeFromLayer:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];
    size_ = [renderer_ backingSize];

    // Avoid flicker. Issue #350
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] drawScene];
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this and how did you correct it. One entry on here discussed destroying the frame buffer and then creating a new frame buffer inside of resizeFromLayer when they were getting a black screen, but that wasn't specific to the AIR. I haven't tried that yet, but will and if it works, I will post that as a possible solution. Some comments on that solution said that it was mask for the real underlying problem, which is why I'm asking this.

The application code builds successfully on both Retina and AIR, but on the iPad and in the simulator, the AIR obviously shows a black screen, since something is failing in the resize.

Comment: I tried tearing down the framebuffer and creating a new one inside resizeFromLayer and I got the same behavior, so that didn't work.

Comment: I have also determined that in resizeFromLayer, layer has rasterizationScale = contentScale == 2 for the iPad Retina, but both equal 1536 for the iPad AIR.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one responded, it took me a while to figure this out, especially since I'm new to xCode, iOS, and cocos2d. The issue turned out to be a 64bit/32bit issue with the older Cocos2d version that was being used. The coordinate offsets were being calculated wrong and the image size was being returned as 0. There was a float/double mismatch which probably would not have occurred if Cocos2d had been upgraded to a newer version.